# java set text size gives different results

Tags: java, android, text-size

for some reason i get two different sizes at lunch when the number inside is the same one is just a number and the second is a math calculation or a variable with math calculation for some reason it gives different sizes on screen

```
paintprecent.setTextSize(35);
paintprecent.setTextSize(mathmade);
```

Comment: What's the value of `mathmade` when the call is made?

Comment: same as without math 35

Comment: Did you verify that with the debugger or by logging the value? I suspect that screen density is a factor here.